# Why is this telling me that my var is undefined?

Tags: javascript

I want to create an alert to force the user to enter a value greater than 0 into an input form before submitting.

Why is it telling me that my `var` is undefined?

```js
function rollDice(bet) {
  bet = document.getElementsByName("startingBet").value;
  if (bet <= 0) {
    alert("You must place a bet");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="luckysevens.html" onsubmit="rollDice()">
  <p>Starting Bet: $ <input type="number" name="startingBet" id="startingBet" /></p>
  <input type="submit" name="play" value="Play" />
</form>
```

Comment: Your function is defined with a parameter, but you call it with no parameter.

Comment: I added the parameter to the call and it still comes back as undefined with console.log(bet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see the reason to bet be undefined since you have assigned bet value. But obviously, the value of bet is `undefined` since you are using `getElementsByName` and it will will have an array-like value and you can not get value on this directly. You'll need to iterate through it. For simplicity you may use `getElementsByName("startingBet")[0]`. But I would suggest you to do the following.

Replace this:

```
document.getElementsByName("startingBet").value;
```

With this:

```
document.getElementById("startingBet").value;
```

Answer (score 2):

`bet` in your function needs a var inside of it. There are no parameters passed to `rollDice()` in your `onsubmit()`. Also please use `let` in place of `var`. Here is the difference between [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) and [var](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var) in javascript.

Here you go:

```js
function rollDice() {
  let bet = document.getElementsById("startingBet").value;
  if (bet <= 0) {
    alert("You must place a bet");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<form action="" onsubmit="rollDice()">
  <p>Starting Bet: $ <input type="number" name="startingBet" id="startingBet" /></p>
  <input type="submit" name="play" value="Play" />
</form>
```

Hope this helps,

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByName` returns a `HTMLCollection`

```js
function rollDice(bet) {
    // assuming funciton parameter as an optional
    const _bet = +(bet || document.getElementsByName("startingBet")[0].value);
    
    // with query selector
    // document.querySelector('[name="startingBet"]').value
    
    // with id selector
    // document.getElementById("startingBet").value;

    if (!_bet) {
        alert("You must place a bet");
        return false;
    }
 }
```

```html
<form action="luckysevens.html" onsubmit="return rollDice()">
        <p>Starting Bet:  $ <input type="number" name="startingBet"id="startingBet" /></p>
        <input type="submit" name="play" value="Play" />    
</form>
```